# View "invalidate" event not called if view not added to activity

Tags: android

I have a background view not showed into main activity and I need to get the "invalidate" event for know when something into the view is changed.

The problem is the event "invalidate" is "emitted" by the view only if this view has been added to the main activity thorugh the "addView" call. I don't want to add this view to main UI since is managed in a separate thread but I have this problem of invalidate event not emitted and I don't know how to find a workaround. It seem the "addview" function unlock something that allow to generate invalidate call but still not found the reasons.

Someone know how to force a view to generate invalidate event also if not added to main activity?

Comment: I've edited your title. See [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/130208/158100) where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this, because invalidate method is called by View framework, so this method would't be called if the view is not add to the window. But I think there's a trick: adding this view to the window and hide it below other view, so this view is invisible and the invalidate method will be called by system.

Comment: This is not correct. The invalidate is called by the internal view "engine" for inform the system that the view need to be repainted. In consequence of this "info" the framework call the onDraw() event but only if the view is currently visible on the screen. At least this is the teory but for some reasons I still didn't know there is something inside the view based class code that doesn't allow the invalidate call to "reach" the final level if the view itslef is not part of activity.

Comment: Regarding your suggestion I can't add the view to the main UI and make it invisible since the view is managed by a separate thread that doesn't allow to be "touched" by something different from the creation thread...

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to invalidate a view that is not there? Instead of finding a workaround I suggest to improve how your app works. Invalidate means that you want to redraw something that is on screen. I don't know your exact use case is but my guess is you want to do something that is not UI related in invalidate. You should not do that.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I dind't explain very well my problem. I don't want to invalidate myself, I override the invalidate method and want to receive the invalidate event informing me that something of graphical is changed into view draw.